# noscript tag not working on iPad and iPod

Tags: javascript, html

I have used noscript tag on master page head section which shows a message when scripting  is disabled on clients browser its working on all device like windows phone and mac PC but, it is show html tags on iPad and iPod when I disable the JavaScript from browser but after refreshing the page it shows the message which one I have placed in noscript tag.
I could not understand what is it for, is there anyone have solution ?
thanks in advance!

```
     <noscript>
        <div class="notify-container" id="Div1">
            <div id="Div2">
                <span class="notify-close" id="Span1"></span><span class="notify-text" id="Span2">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="JavascriptNotEnabledNotification"></asp:Label></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </noscript>
```

above script show the following notification when I disable the JavaScript.

[image]

I am using above tags, it is working in right manner but problem is that when I disable the JavaScript on iPad and iPod devices then above tags are showing on page, instead of showing message.

on iPad and iPod the same page showing the tags instead of notification bar given in following snapshot

[image]

is it noscript tag problem in iPad and iPod or tags are not getting css ?

Comment: should probably show some code or should we make up some elaborate answers?

Comment: It is not clear if the act of disabling javascript shows the tags or if the tags always show until reloaded

Comment: problem is occurring after when I disable the JavaScript, then tag formates of noscript tag are showing on the page only on iPad and iPod.

Comment: But the tags show ONLY right after you disable? If you disable and then load your site, the message is correct?

Comment: yes when I reload the page it displays the notification message, before refreshing it shows the tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      document.write('<style>.noScript { display:none }</style>');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="noScript">Your browser has JS <span style="display:none"> and CSS</span> disabled</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would imply that when stylesheets are disabled, the page shows “Your browser has JS disabled”, whether JS is disabled or not.

Comment: @mplungjan would this script solve the problem you mentioned in the comments of OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

You could instead hide the content you want to display if JavaScript is disabled in your script.  For example, in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.noscript').hide();
});
```

This code will not run if the user has Javascript disabled, thus showing your content.

Comment: That will show the content in JS enabled browsers before hiding it.

Comment: @mplungjan Briefly, yes.  However, it's the only way I know of to adjust content without <noscript> tags.

Comment: @mplungjan Oh, neat.  That's clever.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move your noscript inside the  tag and that should resolve the issue.